# What extra optimisation does g++ do with -Ofast?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction

In g++ 4.6 (or later), what extra optimisations does -Ofast enable other than -ffast-math?

The man page says this option "also enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard compliant programs". Where can I find more information about whether this might affect my program or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a command for checking what options are enabled with -Ofast:

```
$ g++ -c -Q -Ofast --help=optimizers | grep enabled
```

Since I only have g++ 4.4 that doesn't support -Ofast, I can't show you the output.

Answer (score 2):

The -Ofast options might silently enable the gcc [C++ extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html). You should check your sources to see if you make any use of them. In addition, the compiler might turn off some obscure and rarely encountered syntax checking for [digraphs and trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) (this only improves compiler performance, not the speed of the compiled code).